# How can I run a build of React app?

Tags: reactjs

I did a build for a React app using `npm run-script build` and I need to run it. Using `npm run webpack` is returning an error. Excuse my being very new to React but I really need to know how to run this app. I hope you can help!

My package.json:

```
{
"name": "dashboard",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "fast-memoize": "^2.2.8",
    "flow-bin": "^0.52.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.39.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.18.7",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^0.0.3",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-mapbox-gl": "^2.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-redux": "next",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "react-emotion": "^7.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10",
    "styled-components": "^2.1.2"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "flow": "flow"
}
```

[Here are the folders and files of the built app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqCuw.png)

Comment: Might help to show your package.json so we can see what libraries and what scripts you already have.

Comment: @Stretch0 Sure, I edited it.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: You don't appear to be using webpack. Does `npm run build` not create a build file for you?

Comment: @Philippe
Error finding package.json `npm ERR! path /Users/aa/Documents/build/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/aa/Documents/build/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/aa/.npm/_logs/2018-03-08T10_16_56_166Z-debug.log`

Comment: @Stretch0 Yes it does!

Comment: @LeeMoe I have added as an answer. If you could please mark as correct, that would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments.

`npm run build` uses react-scripts to create a build for you

To run in production:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "flow": "flow",
    "start:prod": 'node dist/app.js'
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One more thing: I just realised that I can't run the app statically, aka just by double clicking on index.html, right?

Comment: Correct. You need to use `npm start` to run locally or if you are trying to deploy to production have a start script that runs `node dist/app.js`. Have added example script to answer

Comment: I was wondering about deploying it on server too. Thanks a ton! @Stretch0

Comment: @LeeMoe what do you mean? You can use `node dist/app.js` to run on the server.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at `"react-scripts": "1.0.10"`, it seems you created the app using `create-react-app`.

**create-react-app** is using **yarn** by default. So you can run `yarn` then `yarn build` (same as `npm install` and then `npm run build`)

If you need change webpack configuration. The app have **eject** first. You can do it by `yarn eject`. And then you can edit the webpack config file.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using create-react-app? If yes then run "npm run build" in your root folder. This command will run your app

Comment: The app isn't written by me but I would assume yes it's done using create-react-app because it has those commands in package.json:
`  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }`